# Supported Programming Languages in Salesforce

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app, python

I'm beginner in Salesforce and I have read that the Apex Programming Languages can be used in Salesforce. My Questions is : Can other Programming Languages like Python in Salesforce used ?

Answer (score 13):

### Backend

You cannot use other programming languages for backend development than [Apex](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm), but have in mind that within Salesforce you can use [a great number of APIs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer), from which the most popular ones for developing custom applications are [REST API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_what_is_rest_api.htm) and [SOAP API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_quickstart_intro.htm). For mobile development you can use [Mobile SDK](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/intro.htm).

**May 2022 update:**

Recently, Salesforce has launched a new product that supports writing code in Java and JS (Node) - [Salesforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/overview). Here's a description from the home page:

> Salesforce Functions lets you extend the Customer 360 Platform with
> custom elastically scalable business logic. Salesforce Functions is
> designed to boost developer productivity by reducing your
> infrastructure responsibilities and enabling you to build and
> integrate Functions-as-a-Service (FaaS) apps using the languages and
> tools of your choice.

Some useful links in this area:

- [Get Started with Salesforce Functions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/index.html)
- [Salesforce Functions Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/dev-guide-intro.html)
- [Explore Solutions and Sample Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/platform/functions/guide/solutions_and_samples.html)

---

### Frontend

Also, Salesforce frontend development is basically a JavaScript. The newest framework - [Lightning Web Components Framework](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc) uses [W3C Web Components Standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components). Apps written in LWC can perform [basic database operations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.data).

You can also host apps written in other JS frameworks what's nicely explained in this article: [Lightning Container Component: Building Components with React, Angular, and Other Libraries](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2018/04/lightning-container-component-building-components-with-react-angular-and-other-libraries.html)

Comment: A good answer because it considers that you could integrate between a server running Python (or something else) and the Salesforce org. (Obviously this integration isn't necessarily trivial, so if you don't need to use some external system and can implement the solution fully within Salesforce using Salesforce technology this will be "simplest".)

Answer (score 10):

No. All server-side code must be written in Apex.

Answer (score 6):

Shortly(Dev preview feb 2020) we will get Evergreen function that will allow you to write nodejs and Java code in Salesforce org.

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2019/11/introducing-salesforce-evergreen.html

Given that Salesforce has acquired Heroku few years back, there is a strong possibility that you might get Python. Safe harbor ofc.